Angular Server throwing error, but API call is working and the error is not on browser
I have an API that receives the JWT token in the URL of the API call to return user information.
My function:
getUserByTokenJWT UseCase
executes normally and manages to complete the fields, with the browser returning the correct information in the console.log:
Browser return
However, the Angular server is throwing an error because it tries to make the call first without the token.
Angular SSR console return
I'm not sure why it's doing that or how to fix it. I've already tried adjusting the asynchronicity, but nothing seems to work.
I tried adjusting the asynchronicity, attempted to make the cookie service asynchronous using switch map, and also tested altering the security settings of my backend. However, it still expects the JWT token, which is not being concatenated on server side, even though it doesn't stop my useCase, only throw this error on angular server console.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
